# How to convert Blob to Mat in java opencv?

Tags: java, opencv

I am trying to get images from MySQL database stored as blob and convert them into Mat object for image processing. I have a template image and want to know if that image is part of db image or not using `matchTemplate()` function.  Here is my code:

```
String sql="select * from image_data where image_id="+1
try
        {
            query obj_query=new query(obj_connect);
            ResultSet rs = obj_query.runSimpleQuery(sql);
            while (rs.next()) 
            {
                Blob image_blob=rs.getBlob("original_image");
                Mat img=Imgcodecs.imread(image_blob.toString());            
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
Mat templ=Imgcodecs.imread("templ.png");
```

Passing these images in `findTemplate` function:

```
MatchTemplate.findTemplete(img, templ, "ress.png", Imgproc.TM_SQDIFF);
```

And here is my `findTemplate` function:

```
public static void findTemplete(Mat img, Mat templ, int match_method) 
     {
        double minVal;
        int result_cols = img.cols() - templ.cols() + 1;
        int result_rows = img.rows() - templ.rows() + 1;
        Mat result = new Mat(result_rows, result_cols, CvType.CV_32FC1);
        Imgproc.matchTemplate(img, templ, result, match_method);
        MinMaxLocResult mmr = Core.minMaxLoc(result);
        minVal = mmr.minVal;
        if(minVal<=0.75){
            //do what you want
        }
        else
        {
            //do what you want
        }
    }
```

When I run it, it gives me an error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (s >= 0) in cv::setSize, file C:\builds\master_PackSlaveAddon-win32-vc12-static\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp, line 306
Exception in thread "main" CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: C:\builds\master_PackSlaveAddon-win32-vc12-static\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp:306: error: (-215) s >= 0 in function cv::setSize
]
    at org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat(Native Method)
    at org.opencv.core.Mat.<init>(Mat.java:37)
```

Line on which it gives me the error is:

```
Mat result = new Mat(result_rows, result_cols, CvType.CV_32FC1);
```

How can I handle Blob image to pass it in `Imagecodecs.imread()` function? Or is there another technique to convert `Blob` to `Mat`?

Comment: You should probably use `imdecode` instead of `imread`. Have a look also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32542853/5008845)

Comment: @Miki link that you provided is in c++ code. i am using java and mysql. can you give me java  example.

Answer (score 0):

Simple as this.

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(imageBlob, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
Mat mat_img = new Mat();
Utils.bitmapToMat(img1, mat_img1);
```